# jQuery: change text color of a fixed top navbar at the scrolling of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need help for my personal website. I want to make a one page site with a fixed top navbar (with transparent background). At the scrolling of the page, the color of the menu elements must change dinamically from black to white on the sections that have a dark background (they have a ".dark-bg" class) and return white on the other sections. All sections are 100vh height (except for the menu, of course). This is the HTML main structure of the site:

```
<section class="section--menu fixed-header">                       
    <nav class="menu" id="navigation">
        <ul class="menu__list pull-md-right">
            <li class="menu__item menu__item--current">
                <a class="menu__link" data-target="intro-fabio">home</a>
            </li>                            
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__link" data-target="about-fabio">about</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__link" data-target="skills-fabio">skills</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__link" data-target="works-fabio">works</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
                <a class="menu__link" data-target="contacts-fabio">contacts</a>
            </li>                            
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>

<!-- HOME
======================================================== -->
<section id="intro-fabio">       
</section>   

<!-- ABOUT
======================================================== -->
<section id="about-fabio" class="dark-bg">     
</section>

<!-- SKILLS
======================================================== -->
<section id="skills-fabio">     
</section>    

<!-- WORKS
======================================================== -->    
<section id="works-fabio" class="dark-bg">       
</section> 

<!-- CONTACTS
======================================================== -->    
<section id="contacts-fabio">       
</section>
```

I wrote this jQuery script but it seems to work only for the last section with ".dark-bg" class.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".dark-bg").each(function() {
        detectBg( $(this) );
    });

    function detectBg(sezione) { 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var finestra = $(window).scrollTop();
            var sezCurr = sezione.offset().top;
            var sezNext = sezione.next().offset().top;            

            if (finestra >= sezCurr && finestra < sezNext) {
                $('.menu__link').css("color", "#ebebeb");
            }
            else {
                $('.menu__link').css("color", "#1c1c1c");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it only work with `.dark-bg` because is the only class is being call by `$(".dark-bg").each(function() { detectBg( $(this) ); });`

Comment: if everything is fixed (heigh), use the [jQuery scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on the body element to determine where the scroll is and ligth up the correct menu...

Comment: this also may help you: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjpKn) I found it here: [Viewport Height for Full Screen Div?](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/viewport-height-for-full-screen-div/#post-161095)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle scroll event of the window, and in that handler, check if any of the dark section is under the menu, if so, then change the color of the menu links. Here is an example of changing the color for all links, but it can be easily extended to do it separately for each link:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var vpHeight = $(window).height();
        var isBlack = false;
        $(".dark-bg").each(function(i, section) {
            if(isBlack) {
             return;
            }
      var offset = $(section).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
           if(((offset + vpHeight) >= 0) && ((offset + vpHeight) <= vpHeight)) {
              isBlack = true;
              return;
           }
       });
       $(".menu__link").css("color", isBlack ? "white" : "black");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  position:fixed;
  background: orange;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

section {
  background:red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.dark-bg {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu__list pull-md-right">
  <li class="menu__item menu__item--current">
    <a class="menu__link" data-target="intro-fabio">home</a>
  </li>                            
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" data-target="about-fabio">about</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" data-target="skills-fabio">skills</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" data-target="works-fabio">works</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" data-target="contacts-fabio">contacts</a>
  </li>                            
</ul>


<!-- HOME
======================================================== -->
<section id="intro-fabio">       
</section>   

<!-- ABOUT
======================================================== -->
<section id="about-fabio" class="dark-bg">     
</section>

<!-- SKILLS
======================================================== -->
<section id="skills-fabio">     
</section>    

<!-- WORKS
======================================================== -->    
<section id="works-fabio" class="dark-bg">       
</section> 

<!-- CONTACTS
======================================================== -->    
<section id="contacts-fabio">       
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you xxxmatko for this solution! There was only a little problem with the last section. For my website I made a modification to the second if statement: 

            var posSez = $(section).offset().top;
            var posWin = $(window).scrollTop();

            if( ( posWin >= posSez ) && ( posWin < (posSez + vpHeight) ) ) {
              isBlack = true;
              return;
            }